# Positive frequency modes and lightlike coordinates

Tags: black-holes, radiation, hawking-radiation, qft-in-curved-spacetime

My question is about defining positive frequency modes of radiation in a generic (static) spacetime. I mean, take a black hole and Eddington-Finkelstein null coordinates; $u$ and $v$ are Killing coordinates respectively on past and future horizons. 
Now I know that in a generic static spacetime I can define positive frequency modes through timelike killing vectors; 
I'm a bit confused because studying collapsing black holes, as far as the asymptotically flat regions are concerned, I can define positive frequency radiation modes as $e^{-i \omega v}$ (same with $u$). 
How can I do it if killing parameters $u$, $v$ are lightlike and not timelike?